# Newly created div goes to the bottom of the (Ii) list instead in to the selected (li) element?

Tags: javascript, html

I will go straight to the issue
first concept: I want a div to be created once a user press an icon in a certain area of the html.
my most achieving is that the div get created but I want the creation to be index specific instead it goes to the bottom of the Li list which has some other items also I was able to show it inside the li element as well but it doesn't sere my purpose
I want the div to appear right under the li element that has the icon that has been just clicked
matching this patter

// if first icon clicked the UI must look like following
Ul
LI
Div Are you sure ???
LI
LI
UL

any idea ? thanks for help.

```js
function removeDay() {
  // Select all trash cans 
  let trash = document.getElementsByClassName('fa-trash-alt');
  let divs = document.getElementsByClassName("day-row");
  //Foorloop all trash cans on visible elemenst
  for (let i = 0, len = trash.length; i < len; i++) {
    (function(index) {
      trash[i].onclick =
        function() {

          //new div should apper under the the li element asking you if you are cool with delete
          const areYouSure = `<div class="areYouSure faderin">
          <p>Are you sure ?</p>
          <span>Yes</span>
          <span>No</span>
          </div>`
          this.parentElement.parentElement.innerHTML += areYouSure;
          // if user select yes then do the folowing 
          // if user selen no then don't do anything 
          //alert(index); Helpfull !! 
          //setting timeout for the emlement to remove element an effect 
          //setTimeout(function () { divs[i].style.display = "none"; }, 2000);
          //setTimeout(function () { divs[i].classList.add("faderclick") }, 1000);*/
        }
    })(i);
  }
}
removeDay()
```

```html
<li id="Days" class="day-row">
  <div class="dayFunction">
    <i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-archive"></i>
  </div>
</li>
<li id="Days" class="day-row">
  <div class="dayFunction">
    <i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-archive"></i>
  </div>
</li>

<li id="Days" class="day-row">
  <div class="dayFunction">
    <i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-archive"></i>
  </div>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could achieve your goal through CSS, so i added to your original divs a display style as a flexbox by using style attribute `style="display:flex;"` and set the message div to margin-left with 1rem, using `style="margin-left:1rem;"` so you can have your message in the same line beside your icons with 1rem gap.

Try the snippet, best of luck =)

**EDIT** : As per your request, appended the message to the `<li>` and added display:inline; to the div to keep showing in the same line.

Also added a console log check for the first `<li>`

```js
function removeDay() {
  // Select all trash cans 
  let trash = document.getElementsByClassName('fa-trash-alt');
  let divs = document.getElementsByClassName("day-row");
  //Foorloop all trash cans on visible elemenst
  for (let i = 0, len = trash.length; i < len; i++) {
    (function(index) {
      trash[i].onclick =
        function() {

          //new div should apper under the the li element asking you if you are cool with delete
          const areYouSure = `<div class="areYouSure faderin" style="display:inline;margin-left:1rem;">
          Are you sure ?
          <span>Yes</span>
          <span>No</span>
          </span>`
          this.parentElement.outerHTML += areYouSure;
                  console.log(document.querySelector('li').innerHTML);

          // if user select yes then do the folowing 
          // if user selen no then don't do anything 
          //alert(index); Helpfull !! 
          //setting timeout for the emlement to remove element an effect 
          //setTimeout(function () { divs[i].style.display = "none"; }, 2000);
          //setTimeout(function () { divs[i].classList.add("faderclick") }, 1000);*/
        }
    })(i);
  }
}
removeDay()
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css">
<script src='https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js'></script>


<li id="Days" class="day-row" style="display:flex;">
  <div class="dayFunction">
    <i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-archive"></i>
  </div>
</li>
<li id="Days" class="day-row" style="display:flex;">
  <div class="dayFunction">
    <i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-archive"></i>
  </div>
</li>

<li id="Days" class="day-row" style="display:flex;">
  <div class="dayFunction">
    <i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-archive"></i>
  </div>
</li>
```

Comment: is there a way to specifically append the new div under the li ?? or to the li ?

Comment: @Complex86 would you check the snippet now ?

Comment: that is it, thanks for the solution, it's working so the outer html puts the element on the outer side of the targeted element rather than on the inside ?? again thanks a lot for the great effort and the best solution. have nice day.

Answer (score 0):

Create the div manually in the HTML, then change the visibility or attributes in JavaScript. That way you have full control of positioning and size.

Comment: good option but I am working on a structure that I want to the smallest HTML code as possible and I want all the extra html to be dynamic on demand not pre coded.